# swf to pdf using php

Tags: php, flash

Is there any way to convert a SWF to pdf using php. i mean the page has a button on the click it must export the swf contents in pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you could try is to use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to convert the swf to a series of jpeg images, one per frame, using the 'image2' output codec (see [this part of manual](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC5)). Then you can select the appropriate frame and build a PDF with it using [pdflib](http://www.pdflib.com/), [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) or similar library.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed your question states using php, but I was pretty happy with this library:
[AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.org/). It's worth a try.