# SWF to PDF conversion with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [swf to pdf using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006291/swf-to-pdf-using-php)

I am a new bee and is facing a challenge. Can any body tell me that is it possible to convert swf to pdf with php. Also, if some body has any code regarding this will be a real help for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349082/how-to-convert-pdf-to-swf-using-php

Comment: The first question is asking the reverse, and the second does not have very good answers.

Answer (score 0):

I use CutyCapt for this. It takes HTML and renders it to PDF/PNG/etc. It will also render any Flash embedded in the HTML if Flash is installed. You'll need:

- CutyCapt - http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/
- X11 + xvfb/xvfb-run (headless X11) - here's xvfb-run if your distro doesn't support it: https://github.com/revnode/xvfb-run
- Flash plugin

Code:

```
$input = '/home/test/test.swf';
$output = '/home/test/test.pdf';

$html_file = '/tmp/' . uniqid('flash') . '.html';
$fh = fopen($html_file, 'w');

// some basic HTML to embed the flash
$html = <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<style type="text/css">
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<object width="1000" height="600" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="file://{$input}">
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
<param name="allownetworking" value="always" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</object>
</body>
</html>
EOT;

fwrite($fh, $html);
fclose($fh);

exec("xvfb-run --server-args=\"-screen 0, 1024x768x24\" CutyCapt --plugins=on --out-format=pdf --delay=500 --url=\"{$html_file}\" --out={$output}");

// cleanup
unlink($html_file);
```